# Dynamic print not working with array function

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how to set a dynamic print area that includes an array function that spits out data from another sheet on rows 19-47. I want to print A1 to G whatever is the last row of data is.

I've tried doing the dynamic print using the name manager and changing the print area formula to this
`=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,18+COUNTA($A$19:$A$47),7)` but it goes down to row 47, however it works if there is no array functions in A19:A47.

I can get the row number using the match and lookup function and then concatenate it to what I need.
`=CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(1,1),":$G$",MATCH(LOOKUP($E$7,A19:A47),A1:A47,0))` which gives me something like $A$1:$G$24. Any way to use this?

Or other ideas? Preferably without using VBA because this will hopefully be only used on Excel Online and VBA doesn't work for my org.

Comment: just use the match in the offset: `=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,MATCH(LOOKUP($E$7,A19:A47),A1:A47,0),7)`

Comment: I see why that should work but it isn't. Let me play around with it.

Comment: Okay I think it worked. Need to make all of the ranges absolute.